# How to pull out information from a long string of data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this data point:

```
455-U-202007302233,455-L-202007302233,422-U-202008011052,422-L-202008011052,857-U-202008041142,857-L-202008061215
```

Column: ,[t810str]

How would I be able to modify column [t810str] in order to pull out the last comma set before 857?

```
Desired Result = 422-L-202008011052
```

Comment: Not storing delimited data in your database is the *real* solution here. Then you can simply use `LAG`/`LEAD` to get the prior/next result.

Comment: I wish I could modify the database but I do not have the rights - is there another way?

Comment: What happens if you have 2 (or more) values that start with `857`?

Comment: I just need to get the last string before the string 857 - the last data points will always end with 857. Just need the one before.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to implement some kind of splitter that respects ordinal position (`STRING_SPLIT` does not). I'm therefore going to make use of [`DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2). Then you can split the value, and use `LAG` to get the prior value. Finally you can filter on where the item has a value `LIKE '857%'` but the previous does not:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT DS.Item,
           LAG(DS.Item) OVER (PARTITION BY YourColumn ORDER BY DS.itemNumber) AS PrevItem
    FROM (VALUES('455-U-202007302233,455-L-202007302233,422-U-202008011052,422-L-202008011052,857-U-202008041142,857-L-202008061215'))V(YourColumn)
         CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(V.YourColumn,',') DS)
SELECT C.PrevItem
FROM CTE C
WHERE C.Item LIKE '857%'
  AND C.PrevItem NOT LIKE '857%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your data and the assumption that items are 18 characters (your data do not indicate otherwise):

```
DECLARE @t AS NVARCHAR(255) = '455-U-202007302233,455-L-202007302233,422-U-202008011052,422-L-202008011052,857-U-202008041142,857-L-202008061215';

SELECT RIGHT(LEFT(@t,CHARINDEX(',857',@t)-1),18)
```

[image]

Comment: Elegant and simple :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `cross apply` (which you can also rewrite using a CTE or a subquery for readability). This removes everything after first occurrence of 857 and then grabs the last set that's left. So even if you have multiple 857 and varying length of delimited strings, this should work

```
select *, right(remind , charindex (',' ,reverse(remind))-1)
from t t1
cross apply (select stuff(col, charindex(',857',col), len(col),'') as remind) t2
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=96fe14a8289077a4345937eb8019f93a)

Answer (score 0):

Implemented with string functions (and assuming your data items can have variable length :-) it might look a bit confusing (therefore I'd prefer @Larnu's answer):

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(2000) = '455-U-202007302233,455-L-202007302233,422-U-202008011052,422-L-202008011052,857-U-202008041142,857-L-202008061215'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@string, CHARINDEX(',857',@string) - CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE( LEFT(@string,  PATINDEX('%,857%',@string) - 1)) ) + 1, CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE( LEFT(@string,  PATINDEX('%,857%',@string) - 1)))-1 )
```

Parts of the latter separated:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(2000) = '455-U-202007302233,455-L-202007302233,422-U-202008011052,422-L-202008011052,857-U-202008041142,857-L-202008061215'SELECT CHARINDEX(',857',@string)
SELECT LEFT(@string,  PATINDEX('%,857%',@string) - 1)
SELECT REVERSE( LEFT(@string,  PATINDEX('%,857%',@string) - 1) )
SELECT CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE( LEFT(@string,  PATINDEX('%,857%',@string) - 1)) )
```

Comment: So I have many data points like the one I used for this question - that being said, how would I set the declare to encompass all of the data rather than just that single string? Example: (1) 216-U-202007131825,216-L-202007131832,857-U-202007140125,292-L-202007142005,309-U-202007161356,309-L-202007161356,309-U-202007170618,309-L-202007170619,857-U-202007211323,857-L-202007220237.  Example (2): 671-U-202007162110,671-L-202007162110,857-U-202007221632,857-L-202007221632

Comment: @DrewMurray Just replace the variable `@string` with a column name to use this expression in e.g. SELECT statements.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution use a recursive CTE

```
DECLARE @Var VARCHAR(200) = '455-U-202007302233,455-L-202007302233,422-U-202008011052,422-L-202008011052,857-U-202008041142,857-L-202008061215';

WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT 0 N, LEFT(@Var, CHARINDEX(',', @Var)-1) Part,
         RIGHT(@Var, LEN(@Var) - CHARINDEX(',', @Var)) Remind
  UNION ALL
  SELECT N + 1, 
         LEFT(Remind, CHARINDEX(',', Remind) - 1),
         RIGHT(Remind, LEN(Remind) - CHARINDEX(',', Remind))
  FROM CTE
  WHERE CHARINDEX(',', Remind) <> 0
)
SELECT TOP 1 Part
FROM CTE
WHERE LEFT(Remind, 3) = '857'
ORDER BY N;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=67cb04f7cab3805ef2cbb838c0e36598)